# Android-Java Set Array Contents Equal to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

I'm attempting to set an array in the ImageAdapter (pics) equal to JSON contents in the arrayList called mComments.  I cannot seem to accomplish this by using a toArray() method on the mComments and also typecasting didn't work. I'm trying to use the JSON content to set the images in the GridView instead of the hard-coded resources.  See my ImageAdapter class below and also the relevant calling class.  Full classes available upon request and here is the JSON URL if that helps: https://shipstudent.com/complaint_desk/androidImageFetch.php.  Please let me know if you need more information.

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context=c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pics.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView iv;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            iv = new ImageView(context);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350,350));
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            iv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            iv = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        iv.setImageResource(pics[position]);
        return iv;

    }

    public Integer[] pics={
            R.drawable.menu ,R.drawable.dog,
            R.drawable.favorites,R.drawable.pmlimage,
            R.drawable.progress,R.drawable.hearsay,
//            R.drawable.sample_6,R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Calling Class:

```
private JSONArray mComments = null;

    public void updateJSONdata() {

        // Instantiate the arraylist to contain all the JSON data.
        // we are going to use a bunch of key-value pairs, referring
        // to the json element name, and the content, for example,
        // message it the tag, and "I'm awesome" as the content..

        categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Bro, it's time to power up the J parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Feed the beast our comments url, and it spits us
        // back a JSON object. Boo-yeah Jerome.
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

        // when parsing JSON stuff, we should probably
        // try to catch any exceptions:
        try {

            // I know I said we would check if "Posts were Avail." (success==1)
            // before we tried to read the individual posts, but I lied...
            // mComments will tell us how many "posts" or comments are
            // available
            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag
                String comment = c.getString(TAG_COMMENT);
                String filename = c.getString(TAG_FILENAME);
                String IDUser = c.getString(TAG_IDUser);

                System.out.print(comment);
                System.out.print(filename);
                System.out.print(IDUser);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_COMMENT, comment);
                map.put(TAG_FILENAME, filename);
                map.put(TAG_IDUser, IDUser);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                categoryList.add(map);

            }




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {
        // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to do
        //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
        //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
        //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
        //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
        //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.
//      ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getActivity(), categoryList,
//              R.layout.categories_list, new String[] { TAG_CATEGORY_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.title });
//
//      // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
//      setListAdapter(adapter);
        //imageAdapter.pics = (Integer[]) categoryList.clone(); 

        System.out.print(categoryList.toString());
    }
```

Comment: So you want all the information in your JSON array to be displayed in your ListView??

Comment: No, I want to assign the mComments content String filename = c.getString(TAG_FILENAME); to the pics array in the ImageAdapter class.